# Facebook Graph API wont return photo source for photos uploaded by apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When getting the "me/home" stream there is a difference between the photo objects i get in return. Some of them are returned with the source field (URL to the actual picture) and some not.

After investigating i learned that for photos uploaded to Facebook using the website itself there is the source and images fields in the object,
But for photos uploaded to Facebook by some kind of app (has the "application" field) there are no source/images fields, only a "link" field which direct me to the photo page (whole page, not just the photo)

Does that means i cant get the actual picture file for pics uploaded by apps ? am i missing something?

**Update:** The photos without the source field are "public".

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to get very detailed information about the photo

`SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid='{photoId}'`

For more information on what you can get from the FQL table see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

*Note: the quotes around the photo id is required as it is a string value*